# how to call my url with sub domain using url rewrite iis 7.0

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I have url http://www.traveloista.com/asiatrip/home.aspx, how can i change if some one type asiatrip.traveloista.com, it will show www.traveloista.com/asiatrip.aspx ?

I am using IIS 7.0 and Asp.net vb 4.0

Comment: ```window.location.href("www.traveloista.com/asiatrip.aspx")``` will set the browser url without reloading.

Comment: I mean its like url rewrite, i want create sub domain with url rewrite on IIS 7.0, any example for this